# Center a TextView below an ImageView in a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview, tablelayout, tablerow

how can I **center a TextView below an ImageView in a TableLayout**? I see that I have to use *center_horizontal* with a specified *layout_width* in *dp*:

```
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

[image]

...but my **text value is not always the same**, I set it programmatically and if it's too long:

[image]

So I set *android:singleLine* to *true*:

```
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:singleLine="true"
```

[image]

So I set *layout_width* to *wrap_content* but in this way *center_horizontal* is not working :(

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:singleLine="true"
```

[image]

This is my TableRow layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table_row_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <!-- Left column -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/item_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left_name"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/left_image"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/left_image"
            android:layout_below="@+id/left_image"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="ITEM TEXT VIEW"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


        <!-- Right column -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/left_name"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/item_image"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right_name"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/right_image"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/right_image"
            android:layout_below="@+id/right_image"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="ITEM TEXT VIEW" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Anyone can help me?

UPDATE: This my real layout element:

[image]

Comment: Do you have to do a table layout?

Comment: Hi, I need a layout with 2 colums, if there is a better layout it's ok ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `RelativeLayout`s instead of one. Check this XML,

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table_row_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="0.5">

        <!-- Left column -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/item_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/left_image"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="ITEM TEXT VIEW"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="0.5">
        <!-- Right column -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/item_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/right_image"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="ITEM TEXT VIEW"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: I solved using wrap_content to TextView instead of 90dp and putting android:layout_centerHorizontal="true", if you edit your answer I check it as correct. Thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

*RelativeLayout* is not a best suit for this scenario.It's better to replace with two *LinearLayout*s. The advantage is, you can avoid most of the magic numbers like margins and paddings. Try this layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table_row_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <!-- Left column -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/circle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/left_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="ITEM TEXT VIEW" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Right column -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="ITEM TEXT VIEW" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for ou answer but I need to use a RelativeLayout because I have another textView near the ImageView, I have updated my question with my real layout